The specified https binding is invalid
I am creating a website dynamically using ServerManager, but I am getting the exception "the specified https binding is invalid" on serverManager.Sites.Add("PaintPartnerAPI", "http", "localhost:8080", path);
Complete code
using(var serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
      string path = @"C:\\inetpub\\ppapi\\";
      if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
      {
          System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
      }
      var site = serverManager.Sites.Add("PaintPartnerAPI", "http", "localhost:8080", path);
      serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add("PPApplicationPool");
      serverManager.Sites["PaintPartnerAPI"].Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName = "PPApplicationPool";
      ApplicationPool apppool = serverManager.ApplicationPools["PPApplicationPool"];
      apppool.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;
      site.ApplicationDefaults.EnabledProtocols = "http,https";
      serverManager.CommitChanges();
      apppool.Recycle(); 
  }


The changes you need to make are as follows:

Replace localhost:8080 in the binding information with *. This means that the site will listen on all available IP addresses on the server.
Removed https from enabled protocols since you are just creating an HTTP site.


Replace:
var site = serverManager.Sites.Add("PaintPartnerAPI", "http", "localhost:8080", path);

With:
var site = serverManager.Sites.Add("PaintPartnerAPI", "http", "*:8080:localhost", path);

or with
var site = serverManager.Sites.Add("PaintPartnerAPI", "http", "*:8080:", path);

Please read the documentation about bindingInformation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.binding.bindinginformation?view=iis-dotnet

The value of this property is a colon-delimited string that includes
the IP address, port, and host name of the binding. You can leave the
host name blank. You can set the IP address to "*" to indicate that
the binding works for all variables.
For example, a binding that is set for all IP addresses on port 80 and
has no specified host name returns ":80:" from this property. A
binding that is set for IP address 192.168.1.150 on port 8080 returns
"192.168.1.150:8080:". A binding that is set for all IP addresses on
port 80 for a host named "microsoft.com" returns ":80:microsoft.com".

